# How to bind NSAttributedString to UITextView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

we are using MVVMCross and we are having trouble binding an NSAttributedString to a UITextView. It's weird because the same code works without using a BindingSet and also using Bindig for Text property instead of AttributedText

As said, this line of code is not binding, the TextView just shows the default text:

```
set.Bind (TxtActivityText).For(txt => txt.AttributedText).To (vm => vm.Activity).WithConversion("ActivitySpanMessage");
```

... and outputs the following warning: 
**"MvxBind:Warning: 6.06 Failed to create target binding for binding AttributedText for Activity"**

While with this line is working fine:

```
set.Bind (TxtActivityText).For(txt => txt.Text).To (vm => vm.Activity).WithConversion("ActivitySpanMessage"); // Works fine also binding to the default property
```

And finally, without using bindings it works fine too:

```
TxtActivityText.AttributedText = SpanMessageHelper.ConvertToAttributedString(ViewModel.Activity, null, null, null); // This function is the same I call in the ActivitySpanMessageConverter
```

Any ideas? May this be a bug?

Comment: Is there any debug information in trace? Is there any more info you can provide in the question - e.g. some code values that are used? it "may be a bug"(TM) but others have seen Attributed Text binding working fine - eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934294/how-to-bind-nsattributestring-or-nsmutableattributedstring and https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/791

Comment: Yes, it says MvxBind:Warning:  6.06 Failed to create target binding for binding AttributedText for Activity. It's weird because it's a pretty simple casa: simple XIB done with xCode6 with some other controls working fine. Tomorrow I'll try if its a problem with the simulator

Comment: Please edit the question to include the relevant trace and information - it's easier to read in the question than it is in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because the Xamarin linker is not including UITextView.AttributedText since it is only used in an expression. See this post for more info: [MvvmCross Failed to create target binding for EditingDidBegin on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102503/mvvmcross-failed-to-create-target-binding-for-editingdidbegin-on-iphone)

You can fix this by going to LinkerPleaseInclude.cs and changing your UITextView include method:

```
public void Include(UITextView textView)
{
    textView.Text = textView.Text + "";
    textView.Changed += (sender, args) => { textView.Text = ""; };

    // Add this line here
    textView.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString();
}
```